# How to use nuxt-property-decorator in codesandbox?

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, codesandbox

I want to make sample code in CodeSandBox.
And I have tried to install "nuxt-property-decrator" to use "@Component".
But I added "nuxt-property-decorator" to dependencies, error message occurred and
if I add some component, it never render.
Does someone advise me, please?

```
    <script lang="ts">
import {Component,Vue} from 'nuxt-property-decorator'
@Component({})
```

[error message in @Cmppoent({})]
(alias) Component(options: ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData, DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string, any>>, Record<...>> & ThisType<...>): (target: VC) => VC (+1 overload)
import Component